# KeyGenerator a special Key vs a special Seed

Tags: java, random, seed

Is this correct that `RandomGenerator` should generate a unique key for each unique seed?

I wrote the following code, but for the same seed it generates different byte arrays - why?

```
public static byte[] getRawKey(byte [] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr);
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}
```

Comment: You're using `SecureRandom`. What happens with plain `Random`?

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of SecureRandom says:

> Many SecureRandom implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed. Other implementations may produce true random numbers, and yet others may use a combination of both techniques.

So, no, SecureRandom doesn't make any guarantee that what it produces is deterministically determined by the value of its seed. To the contrary: a SecureRandom is more secure if it is not a PRNG producing a deterministic sequence based on a seed.